# Ubuntu/Xubuntu install crashes when trying to add partition

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, xubuntu

I just got a new hard drive and I want to put linux on it, but i cant install it due to the above problem. I've even tried making a new partition in GParted, but it doesn't show when trying to install. If I click on the plus, minus, or change buttons, the installer crashes. In ubuntu it freezes for about 30 seconds, and in xubuntu it crashes right away.

When type `sudo fdisk -l` in the console this is the output:

```
    Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
    255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
    Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    Disk identifier: 0x47531277

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1       123877376  1936748543   906435584   83  Linux

Disk /dev/sdb: 16.0 GB, 16039018496 bytes
64 heads, 32 sectors/track, 15296 cylinders, total 31326208 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00094134

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *          32    31326207    15663088    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

This is what it looks like in GParted

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu. Could you please give more details about your problem?

Comment: Can you open a terminal from the live usb and run this command and paste the output into your question as an edit: sudo fdisk -l

Comment: At first glance it looks like the installer isn't recognizing the drive, but fdisk seems to disagree with that...

Answer (score 1):

[SOLVED]

It was a problem with the specific hard drive I was using. I put in a another one and it works perfectly fine.